# Forgetfull functor from Set and Top admits adjoints

Tags: category-theory

Is there any book or article where I can find some completely explained examples of adjunctions?

I just don't know how to make a complete prove that, for instance in $\mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{Top}$ the forgetfull functor admits a left and a right adjoint via unit and counit.

Can someone help me? I tried to understand from the book of Harold Simmons, but I don't understood completely.

Comment: **Hint:** The left adjoint is the functor $\bf Set\to\bf Top$ which sends every set to the *discrete* topological space on itself, and the right adjoint sends every set to its *codiscrete* topological space (where only $\emptyset$ and the full space are open).

Comment: How can I define the co-unity $\varepsilon_{(X,\tau)}: (X, \mathcal{P}(X))\to (X,\tau)$?

Comment: This is the identity function on $X$. And it is continuous: the preimage of every open set (i.e. element of $\tau$) is open (because of the discreteness).